# Parsing of function-like macros and arguments

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, language-lawyer

1) In C, you can write a function-like macro like `example1` in the following snippet:

```
#define first(a, b)   a
#define second(a, b)  b

#define example1(x) splitting the tuple:  [first x] and [second x]
example1((1, 2))
```

which expands to `splitting the tuple: [1] and [2]`. This is because the arguments are expanded before the `first` and `second` macro names are recognized as such.

2) As an extension, you can also easily remove parentheses from an argument using variadic macros:

```
#define unparen(...)  __VA_ARGS__
#define example2(x) removing parentheses:  unparen x
example2((1, 2))
```

which expands to `removing parentheses: 1, 2`.

3) However the following doesn't work:

```
#define example3(x) splitting the tuple: [first(unparen x)] and [second(unparen x)]
example3((1, 2))
```

The error from cpp is the following:

```
test.c:12:16: error: macro "first" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
test.c:12:16: error: macro "second" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
```

that is, the parenthesized arguments of `first` and `second` are gobbled *before* `unparen` is expanded. This seems to contradict point (1). How does this work in terms of the macro expansion algorithm in the C standard, and what would break if it were allowed?

Comment: ah no, `unparen x` does *not* need the parentheses. That's the point of it.

Comment: you know what: just don't bother. Tricks like this lead to confusing nonsense (as evidenced by my erroneous edit).

Comment: I don't get your example, the syntax doesn't make any sense. Is this supposed to be a string or what? How do you turn that macro into a string? You can't.

Comment: @Lundin If you take the first one, the first thing that happens is the `x`s are replaced by `(1, 2)` so you get `first x -> first (1, 2)`. I'm surprised it works to be honest.

Comment: @JeremyP Yes. But how are you going to turn `splitting the tuple:  [first (1,2)] and [second (1,2)]` into valid C preprocessor tokens?

Comment: @Lundin they already are valid preprocessing tokens `first (1,2)` is a valid macro call. As I said I was surprised that it works, but it does (at least with the clang preprocessor)..

Comment: @JeremyP What I mean is, how are you going to integrate this macro as-is, in a real-world C program? I don't see any way to do that. Writing some goo that will be pre-processed but never used fills no purpose.

Comment: @Lundin you aren't. This has, as far as I can tell, no practical use in the world of C programming and if any member of my team tried it, they would be roasted over a low flame - metaphorically.

Comment: @Lundin: the "exampleN" macros of course are not meant for use in a real-world C program. But I actually _have_ used this in a real-world program to implement _Generic on a compiler that lacks it.

Comment: @PaoloBonzini Questions that have no real-world use should preferably be tagged with [tag:language-lawyer], indicating that you are only interested in language syntax and not practical use.

Comment: There are _occasional_ uses for preprocessor tricks. But you're right about the tag, I didn't know it (and I have added it now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supplementary answer just to expand on the algorithm:

> the parenthesized arguments of `first` and `second` are gobbled before unparen is expanded. This seems to contradict point (1). How does this work in terms of the macro expansion algorithm in the C standard, and what would break if it were allowed?

This doesn't contradict point (1), because the steps are separated more explicitly than (1) seems to expect - there are three steps, not two.

First, the text of each argument is gathered and assigned to a parameter without performing any macro expansion on it.

Second, the parameters are substituted for their expanded token lists in the replacement list, expanding the arguments independently as we proceed through the replacement list in a linear fashion.

Thirdly, any macros appearing in the replacement list are expanded immediately according to the same rules, which means that if they appear in the argument list of a function-like macro identified *at this step*, they are *not* expanded yet - they are fed back into the first step of the nested expansion.

So the important detail to bear in mind is that all argument expansion happens *after* a function-like macro has been entered, which is the opposite of the order in which arguments are evaluated relative to function bodies in the main C language, and therefore potentially counterintuitive.

So going back to (3), the order is:

1. `example3` is entered
2. `x` is expanded and substituted for the first time*
3. `first` is entered, which fails because of the argument mismatch
4. ignoring the failure, `a` is substituted within `first` for `unparen (1, 2)`
5. only *now*, within the expansion of `first`, can `unparen` be entered

...and so on.

---

* in the presence of language extensions like `__COUNTER__`, re-use of arguments can reveal implementation details, but in the standard language it makes no difference whether the expansion of `x` is cached or re-evaluated

Answer (score 2):

Example three is first expanded to

```
splitting the tuple: [first(unparen (1, 2))] and [second(unparen (1, 2))]
```

And it can be seen that, indeed `first` only has one argument which is `unparen(1, 2)`

To do the `unparen` before `first` and `second` would require the preprocessor to have some semantinc knowledge of what you are trying to do to change the rules of how it applies macro expansion.

Comment: Doh, indeed that's pretty obvious. `unparen (1, 2)` is only expanded when first refers to its argument, and you don't even get to that point because of the wrong number of arguments.